# Kubernetes: How to connect to a postgresql database in k8s from local vm through jdbc

Tags: kubernetes

How can i connect to a postgresql server deployed in K8S cluster from my local VM?Intead to getting inside the pod which runs the DB, I wanted to access it using jdbc.I have created an ingress for the pod which runs the pgserver.Will it be possible to access using a jdbc url created with the ingress hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with ingress hostname or port-forward postgres SVC, access the same in JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.Use the ingress as hostname and port for database using JDBS further you can make the connection with database server.

```
jdbc:postgresql://<database_host>:<port>/<database_name>
```